# apt-get doesn't work

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.7. When I use `apt-get` to install any package, it shows the error：

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.7) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then, I try to use "`sudo apt-get -f install`" but it shows：

```
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8) over (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/gapplication.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/gapplication'): Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb
```

I tried `apt-cache policy libglig2.0-bin` and it shows

```
libglib2.0-bin:
  Installed: 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.7
  Candidate: 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8
  Version table:
     2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8 500
        500 http://repo.huaweicloud.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://repo.huaweicloud.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.48.0-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://repo.huaweicloud.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

The I run `sudo apt upgrade`, the same problem of libglib2.0 appears again.

I also find that I cannot create a new file in the `\usr\bin\` even though I login as the root user. I am wondering if all of the abovementioned problems caused by this?

I have tried a lot of methods but still cannot fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & release specifics, but assuming *xenial* the following shows for one package I looked up (`libglib2.0-0 | 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8       | xenial-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x`) so it looks you've added a 3rd party package that is outdated, or your system hasn't been fully upgraded (I'd `sudo apt update` and check the output is correct without warnings/errors or missing lines)..

Comment: There is one error: ```E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.```. I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Please add `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-bin` as that is requiring an *deprecated* package for 16.04.7

Comment: The PPA `http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl/ubuntu` does not provide support for *xenial* or 16.04; so someone on your system failed their security checks (PPAs are 3rd party sources so all security & fitness for purposes is the responsibility of the admin who has `sudo` rights to perform all checks). Without support since 2014 that PPA should not have been added a 2016/16.04 system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)